# How std::optional library handles emplace operation?

Tags: c++, emplace, stdoptional

I was trying to create objects for optional variables in-place. When using emplace function in std optional library for a class, the destructor of the class is called. Does that function do copy operation or move operation for that classes.

I called emplace function in three different ways and two of them calls the destructor. What is the difference between them?

Basic class:

```
class myClass{
private:
   int m_num;
public:
   myClass(int num) : m_num(num){}
   ~myClass(){
      std::cout << "myClass destructed\n";
   }
};
```

Main:

```
int main(){
   std::optional<myClass> a;
   std::optional<myClass> b;
   std::optional<myClass> c;

   std::cout << "emplacing a: \n";
   a.emplace(myClass{0});
   std::cout << "emplacing b: \n";
   b.emplace<myClass>(0);
   std::cout << "emplacing c: \n";
   c.emplace(0);
   std::cout << "done\n";
   
   while (true) {};    
}
```

output:

```
emplacing a: 
myClass destructed
emplacing b:
myClass destructed
emplacing c:
done
```

Comment: You have several compiler generated methods that don't have print statements in them that are being used. You will get a better view if you add your own versions of Copy Construct / Copy Assignment / Move Constructor / Move Assignment (just for fun add a default Constructor)\

Comment: ok, you are right. But any idea for my example?

Comment: Do the fun part as Martin wrote. You'd need no more coments after that. Make sure to define and print all those functions.

Comment: Just because it got "emplaced" doesn't mean the old one won't get destructed eventually.  A *move* constructor was called meaning that your temporary `myClass` object had an opportunity to move its internals into  `a` before the empty shell of the temporary one got destructed.  You just haven't written your own custom move constructor for `myClass` to see anything interesting happen.  The compiler-generated one will be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I add print statements to all the compiler generated methods I get the following output:

```
emplacing a: 
Constructor: 0
Move Constructor: 0
myClass destructed


emplacing b: 
Constructor: 0
Move Constructor: 0
myClass destructed


emplacing c: 
Constructor: 0

done
myClass destructed
myClass destructed
myClass destructed
```

**Note**: The following statement are based on having either implicit or explicit move constructors created. Which is what I expect the OP is expecting to have answered by the question. BUT one should note that the implicit move constructors for the OPs `myClass` have been disabled because the class has a user defined destructor and thus it would use the copy constructor rather than the move constructor.

So you can see in the first two. You are creating an object of `myClass` which is then being moved into the optional. Then the object that was created is destroyed.

While you third option `c` simply creates the object emplace into the optional.

I removed the infinte final loop. So you can see that after main() exits all three objects remaining are then destroyed.

So what is happening. Usually emplace is written something like this:

```
 template<typename... Args>
 void emplace(Args...&& args)
 {
      // In the first two cases the parameter is `myClass` so
      // simply forward the parameter which invokes the move
      // constructor.
      //
      // In the third case the parameter is an int.
      // So forward this to the constructor of myClass there
      // is a constructor that takes an int so use it.
      createThe_T_object_insidethisobject(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }
```

So in your case:

```
a.emplace(myClass{0});   // Args is myClass
                         // So here you have manually create the myClass
                         // object before even passing it.
                         // This is fine as the forward will then do a perfect forward of the parameter.
```

---

```
b.emplace<myClass>(0);   // Here you are telling the compiler
                         // You are invoking the function using
                         // Args => myClass
                         // So the compiler has to create an R-Value using the values you passed.
                         // Fine. Your user defined constructor works.
                         // Then inside the function you use perfect forwarding.
```

---

```
 c.emplace(0);           // Here Args => int
                         // You forward the parameters to where
                         // the `myclass` object is created.
                         // there is a constructor that takes an
                         // integer so build in place.
```

---

PS. just in case it is not obvious. You should be using technique `c` (as in all C++ questions "usually").

Comment: Yeah, thanks I got it.

Comment: Given the OP is trying to understand the behavior of `emplace` via logging the dtor, move ctor is eventually the most relevant. But he was supposed to do that himself.

Answer (score 0):

A key thing to keep in mind is that `emplace` *always* constructs an object (barring exceptional cases like exceptions being thrown). That is, `emplace` is invoked, *then* an object is constructed, then `emplace` returns.

***Terminology note:** I will refer to types as "matching" to mean that they are "close enough" for the scenario at hand. This is to account for scenarios where, for example, either `T` or `T&` would fit.*

> ```
> a.emplace(myClass{0});
> ```

A function's arguments are evaluated before the function is invoked. In this case, the lone function argument, `myClass{0}`, says to construct a `myClass` object. This happens *before* `emplace` is invoked. Since a `myClass` object will also be constructed after `emplace` is invoked, there are two `myClass` objects constructed in this one line. Only one of these objects survives to the next line, hence the other is destroyed as the line ends.

> ```
> b.emplace<myClass>(0);
> ```

A function's arguments are evaluated before the function is invoked. In this case, the lone function argument, `0`, looks simple, but the template argument, `myClass`, says that the type of this argument must be `myClass`.   So the compiler implicitly constructs a `myClass` object from the `int` to form the actual argument to `emplace`. This happens *before* `emplace` is invoked. We're back in the same case as before.

*Note: The template arguments specify what `emplace` will construct an object from. They should match the parameters of the constructor you intend to use. When the template argument is `myClass`, `emplace` will use the constructor that matches, namely move or copy construction. This is usually not called "in-place" construction.*

> ```
> c.emplace(0);
> ```

In this case, the lone function argument really is simply an `int`.  The template argument for `emplace` is deduced to match, allowing the value `0` to be passed to `emplace` without additional processing. There is only one `myClass` object constructed (which is done after invoking `emplace`), so there are no extra objects to destroy.

---

Forcing the construction of a `MyClass` object before calling `emplace()` is more work on your part and more work on the compiler's part. Don't bother.